# Debugging Memory leak - org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks, spring-data-jpa, sessionfactory

There is a service that connects to Oracle DB for reading data and it uses **Hibernate-3.6** and **SpringData-JPA-1.10.x**. Heap dumps are getting generated frequently which results in out of memory on the hosts.

After analyzing few heapdumps using Eclipse MAT, found that the majority of the memory is accumulated in one instance of **org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext -> org.hibernate.util.IdentityMap -> java.util.LinkedHashMap**.

[image]
And the leak suspect says

> The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0x84427e10 ... : 29 keeps local
>   variables with total size 1,582,637,976 (95.04%) bytes.
>
> The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.LinkedHashMap"
>   loaded by "".

Searched it on StackOverflow and it says SessionFactory should be singleton and session.flush() and session.clear() should be invoked before each call to clear the cache. But *SessionFactory is not explicitly initialized or used in the code*.

**What's causing the memory leak here (looks like the result of each query is cached and not cleared) and how to fix it?**

***More info about the Spring Data configuration:***

TransactionManager is initialized as:

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode='proxy' proxy-target-class='true' />
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
   ....
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" depends-on="...">
   ....
</bean>
```

To interact with the table, an interface is declared extending Spring Data **Repository** and **JpaSpecificationExecutor**. Both are typed into the domain class that it will handle.

API activity method has the annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)`.

Comment: Post your hibernate config and how you are initialized `SessionFactory` .

Comment: Also turn on debug log and post that log also.

Comment: @Amogh As mentioned in the question, SessionFactory is not explicitly initialized or used in the code since we are using Hibernate and Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 4):

From what you describe this is what I expect to be going on:

Hibernate (actually JPA in general) keeps a reference to all entities it loads or saves for the lifetime of the session.

In a typical web application setup, this isn't a problem, because. A new session starts with each request and gets closed once the request is finished and it doesn't involve that many entities.

But for your application, it looks like the session keeps growing and growing.
I can imagine the following reasons:

- something runs in an open session all the time without it ever closing. Maybe something like a batch job or a scheduled job which runs at regular intervals.
- Hibernate is configured in such a way that it reuses the same session without ever closing it.

In order to find the culprit enable logging for opening and closing the session. Judging from https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2425 `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl` should be the right log category and you probably need trace level logging.

Now test the various requests to your server and see if there are any sessions that get opened but not closed.

Comment: This service has multiple API interacting with different tables and looking at the values of IdentityMap, it falls into a specific API. All the APIs in the service follows the same pattern (uses Spring Data Repository and JpaSpecificationExecutor) and couldn't identify why this is happening to a specific one. Also, the traffic to this API is normal and there is no sudden increase. There is no scheduled/batch job that runs at regular intervals. However, the traffic is high at few times due to the usage.

Comment: Also, to add logs at session open/close, does Session obj from EntityManager need to be accessed explicitly in the Repository file? because SessionFactory is not used in the code currently. Can you explain this in detail?

Comment: Since the method is annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)`, it should flush the session cache for each request, right?

Comment: Normally this is handled via the standard configuration of Hibernate and the Spring Transaction mechanism. Spring closes the transaction, which also closes the session. So the question is: Does this happen as intended. If the logs show it doesn't we can look into the configuration to find out why not.

Comment: SUPPORTS mean it will join the current transaction or open an own transaction if no current is available. 
Flush might occur at different times (before a select, before a commit, on request) but only writes changes to the database. It does not empty the session.
Ending the Transaction should also close the Session, so it should gather more resources.

Comment: If the method call encounters an existing Transaction it will join it and if that transaction is for some reason not finishing the session won't close either. This is my current guess what is happening.

Comment: I think it's because of the way the Transactional annotation is defined. It's possible that no transaction is started because of the SUPPORTS propagation mode, so the method effectively uses a local (database) transaction which could use the same session for multiple calls (because hibernate reuses the session). The read-only flag is applied only if a transaction is started. In this case, no transaction was started, so the read-only flag is ignored.

Comment: So, I think changing the Transactional propagation to REQUIRED (which is default) will make use of readOnly (true) properly and should help to resolve this memory leak. Does it make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173073/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-saravanan).

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: @Saravanan any findings on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The question contains information about the creations of some beans. But the problem doesn't lie there. The problem is in your code, where have you use these beans.

Please check your code. Probably you are loading items in a loop. And the loop is wrapped with a transaction.

Hibernate creates huge intermediate objects, and it doesn't clean these before the transaction being completed (commit/rollback).